# Nuxt.js fetch on page reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

When using nuxt.js `fetch()`, whenever I reload the page, it does not fetch it again. Only if I come from a router-link. How do I force it to actually refetch from my API?

```js
export default {
    async fetch() {
        const data = await this.$axios.$get(`/users/${this.$route.params.name}`)
        this.user = data
    },
    data() {
        return {
            user: []
        }
    }
}
```

Every page I look at, they always show placeholders on page refresh, WHILE refetching from their APIs, why does my Nuxt.js app not do that when refreshing? It is just not refetching the data from my API, which is weird.

Answer (score 3):

I believe, in Nuxt.JS, the fetch method is only called on rendering from router navigation - a manual reload would not trigger this.

Perhaps you could construct a mixin using `beforeMount()` instead of `fetch()` and apply this to the pages where this was required.

Or of course, just on the page itself:

```
async beforeMount() {
    const data = await this.$axios.$get(`/users/${this.$route.params.name}`)
    this.user = data
},
```

https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/

Comment: What is the point of using fetch at all then?

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into the same issue.

After browsing the [options section](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#options) of the Nuxt docs on fetch, it looks like  setting the fetchOnServer option to false triggers the fetch hook on both the client-side and when the page reloads (server side), solving the issue:

```
fetchOnServer: false
```

Comment: Ok, but does this not blow away SSR ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems no viable solution for reload issue when doing Nuxt static site. An option for me is calling fetch in mounted hook if data wasn't not loaded in fetch hook:

```
  mounted() {
     if (!this.loaded) this.$fetch()
  },
```

[Fetch as a method](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12#fetch-as-a-method)

Comment: what's wrong with setting `fetchOnServer: false`?

Comment: Yes it's another possibility but will lose static site generation advantage using it as it will tell Nuxt app to use client side only

Comment: what is `this.loaded` ?

Comment: @panjigemilang 
Boolean flag to tell weather the resource has been loaded or not

Comment: is it initiated in `data()` ? wouldn't it be always `false` if I set it to `false`? why didn't I just call the `$fetch()` instead?